# Redirect submit button (Login page)

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I have a little problem. I have a login box with a submit button, but I can't redirect to another page. I insert the email and password but it doesn't works, it just stay on the first page. What can I do?

I use this:

```
header("Location: home.php");
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';
    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="") {
        header("Location: home.php");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    if($row['password']==md5($upass)) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("Location: home.php");
    } else {
?>
<script>alert('wrong details');</script>
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: not enough code there Red.

Comment: probably outputting before header

Comment: can't say without seeing the HTML form and if connection is good or not.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string -  Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement. I think Password doesn't match

Comment: Have you checked if it even go inside `if($row['password']==md5($upass)) {`?

Comment: you have invalid syntax

Comment: check your apache logs and html .

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You really shouldn't use MD5 password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Take a long look at `if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")` - see if the answerer picks up on it... and anyone else for that matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers...I solve the problem using the syntax:  echo "<script>window.location.assign("home.php")</script>";  ... I will try to solve the problem with the Injection Attacks..but I need time I'm a beginner...and that's new for me..the same with the php buit functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
header("Location: home.php");
```

to

```
echo "<script>window.location.assign("home.php")</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

At first `isset($_SESSION['user'])` returns boolean: `true` or `false` not "", so you must use `if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']!="")`.

Second all your `mysql_*` functions are deperecated.

Also will be good to not mix PHP and JS codes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']!='') {
    header("Location: home.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
  $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
  $_SESSION['user']='we have pw';
  if( $row['password']==md5($upass) ) {

      $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
      header("Location: home.php");
} else {?>
      <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
```

Was your password converted to md5 ?? 
in this row should be the problem. 
Mention: if this is your home.php then it will redirect all day .

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="") {
    header("Location: home.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password= 'md5($upass)' ");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
if($row) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
    header("Location: home.php");
} else {
?>
 <script>alert('wrong details');</script>


<?php }} ?>
```

Comment: wow, he is already using mysql which is deprecated and now you remove escape string, the little bit check and security he had now totally vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.