# Is this a session issue?

Tags: php, linux, apache, session

I have this code that works fine on a development machine but when ported over to production the user will get the alert wrong details despite being right.

My guess is this is a session issue with PHP. However, I am seeing session files saved to /tmp on the server. Am I missing something obvious as to what is causing this issue?

The code is referenced below.

```
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
    {
        header("Location: home.php");
    }
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
    {
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `USERS` WHERE `EMAIL` = '$email'");
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
        if($row['PASSWORD']==md5($upass))
            {
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row['ID'];
                header("Location: home.php");
            }
        else
            {
                ?>
                <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
                <?php
            }

    }
```

Comment: The code that checks the email and password doesn't use the session variable. Why would it be a session issue?

Comment: This is invalid syntax `if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")` - you need 2 conditions. check if it's set AND if not equal to.

Comment: why do I feel like I've seen the same question/code multiple times in the last day or so? Edit: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32094350/ I thought so, amongst a few others.

Comment: Plus, we have no idea where your POST arrays are coming from and whether they hold values or not.

Comment: Someone has posted a tutorial with that bad syntax and all these people have looked at it today I recon @Fred-ii- Must be 5 already today

Comment: @RiggsFolly I feel like you are right *kind sir*.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094350/redirect-submit-button-login-page

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "") {
    header("Location: home.php");
}
```

to

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location: home.php");
}
```

For more information check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/1519849/1592783 by karim79. Or if you would like to know about `empty` check out http://php.net/empty

Comment: many love it when an explanation is given. That way, everyone learns. You know what's going on and I know and others, but many who are new to conditional statements and PHP will not. *Food for thought* on your future answers. Tip: it attracts more votes(+). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I made the following changes:

- Fix the `isset()` test of `$_SESSION['user']`. You shouldn't compare it to `""`. Perhaps what you really want is `if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])`.
- Use `elseif`, so that it only checks the email and password when the session variable isn't set.

```php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        header("Location: home.php");
    }
elseif(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
    {
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `USERS` WHERE `EMAIL` = '$email'");
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
        if($row['PASSWORD']==md5($upass))
            {
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row['ID'];
                header("Location: home.php");
            }
        else
            {
                ?>
                <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
                <?php
            }

    }
```

Comment: Still same issue. Not entirely sure as to why it acts as it fails an md5 check.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` on the password, since you're not substituting it into a query.

Comment: Put `var_dump($row['PASSWORD'], md5($upass));` into the `else` clause so you can see what the password is.

Comment: Better yet, don't use MD5 at all, but something more of "this century".

Comment: @Fred-ii- If the logic is wrong, it doesn't matter what password hash he uses. Let's get the logic right first.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't make a mention about their use of MD5. Had I put an answer in and not mentioning that and substituting it for a safe hashing function, people would be all over me. Edit: not to mention their use of `mysql_`.

Answer (score 1):

The **isset** will return only true or false.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
```

Try to change it to

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
```

Or compare the value os the $_SESSION['user'] with:

```
if($_SESSION['user'] == "")
```

Answer (score 0):

So I finally fixed it. Going from Windows to Linux MySQL table names become case sensitive. Did not know that.

Comment: Yeah, * NIX and Windows are two different animals altogether, *everywhere*. Keep that in mind for folder/filename naming conventions also ;-)